# Building JSON to include attributes for use in DataTables

Tags: jquery, json, vbscript, datatables

I've been playing with JQuery DataTables for a few months now and am at the stage where I am using JSON to build the tables as opposed to HTML (ridiculously quicker for the level of data being pulled).

due to the age of the servers and software involved I'm using VBScript (Classic ASP) to build the JSON which I am calling as follows:

```
$().ready(function(){
    $("#example").DataTable({
        "sScrollX": "90%",
        "sScrollXInner": "100%",
        "ajax":'Ajax.asp?RT=test'
    });
});
```

I'm Building the JSON in the ajax.asp file like so

```
response.expires=-1
RequestType=request.querystring("RT")
if RequestType = "test" then
    AjaxSQL="SELECT * FROM table"
    set AjaxRS=Myconn.execute(AjaxSQL)
    ajax="{ 'data': [ "
    Do while not AjaxRS.eof
        ajax=ajax&"['"&AjaxRS("column1")&"', '"&AjaxRS("column2")&"', '"&AjaxRS("column3")&"'],"
        AjaxRS.MoveNext
    loop
    ajax=left(ajax,(len(ajax)-1))
    ajax=ajax&" ] }"
    response.write(replace(ajax,"'",""""))
    AjaxRS.close
    set AjaxRS=nothing
    set AjaxSQL=nothing
end if
```

I know it's far from elegant but it seems to be the only way t o build a JSON with classic asp that works.

The main problem I'm facing is not with the above code. it's with the lack of attributes in the cells that DataTables is rendering.
I use these attributes in JQuery scripts on the page as each cell should have it's own class that I can use to trigger a JQuery event and also attributes such as data-key and data-value which I can pull for use later. an example would be:

```
$(".class").on("click", function(){
    var key=$(this).attr("data-key");
});
```

but I don't know how I can build the attributes into the JSON to then be rendered by the DataTables plugin (by my thinking it has to be at the point of building the JSON because the attribute values directly correlate to the data being pulled from the server, such as the primary key).

No doubt I'm doing something fundamentally wrong and would be very grateful for anyone who can point me in the right direction.

Thank you all

elboffor

::edit::
to clarify what I'm after,
previously I've written attributes in html like so:

```
<td class="classname" data-key="123">column1data</td>
```

What I need to know is:

1. What does the json need to look like?
2. What do I need to include when calling the datatable to render so it reckognises the attributes and writes it in the dom?

This will enable me to use these attributes for further blocks scripts on the page

Comment: Sounds like you need to use object for each row not array. Then you can use other properties of object that aren't field related to set attribute values and use row render callback to set those in the dom

Comment: Thanks for your reply @charlietfl :) I tried using Objects but Datatables just displayed the word object for each element within the object. Like i said i am faily new to this so i may be doing something wrong. to build the sytax i did the following `code` "[{'class':'editable','data':'"&AjaxRS("column1")&"'}, {'class':'editable','data':'"&AjaxRS("column2")&"'}, {'class':'editable','data':'"&AjaxRS("column3")&"'}]" `code` this was just to add class names as a test :/

Comment: when using objects have to define the field name used in each column. Should be example in the docs